# Why my answer is wrong in evaluating $\int_0^\pi \cos^3x dx$ by substitution and how to fix it?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I evaluated the integral as follow, $$\int_0^\pi \cos^3x dx=\int_0^\pi(1-\sin^2x)\cos xdx$$
Here I used the substitution $u=\sin x$ and $du=\cos x dx$ and for $x\in [0,\pi]$ we have $\sin x\in [0,1]$ Hence the integral is,
$$\int_0^11-u^2du=u-\frac{u^3}3\large\vert ^1_0=\small\frac23$$But the answer I got is wrong since  if I evaluate the indefinite integral $\int \cos^3x dx$ I get $\sin x-\dfrac{\sin^3x}{3}$ and now if I apply the interval $[0,\pi]$ I get $\int_0^\pi \cos^3x dx=0$.

My question is why I got the wrong value in my approach and how to fix it?

Comment: $u=0$ when $x=0$ and it is also $0$ when $x=\pi$. How did you get integral from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: To get your new boundaries, you replace $0$ by $\sin 0$ and $\pi$ by $\sin\pi=0$.

Comment: So should both upper and lower boundaries be equal to $0$ and does $\int_0^01-u^2du$ make sense? Or I should evaluate the indefinite integral first then apply the values of boundaries?

Comment: @Amirali yes, the boundaries are both zeros. The term upper and lower boundaries can be misleading, the upper boundary need not be larger than lower boundary and the boundaries need not be minimum and maximum value in the interval.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Thanks a lot! It's clear now.

Comment: Another way that you could see the result for this integral coming is that the function $ \ \cos^3 x \ $ is anti-symmetric about the "vertical line" $ \ x \ = \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ \ , \ $ so the negative "area under the curve" from $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ to $ \ \pi \ $ _exactly cancels_ the positive area from $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution rule can only be applied if the substitution is by a monotonous function. This is not the case for the sine on $[0,\pi]$. You would have to split the domain and apply the substitution rule separately on the intervals $[0,\frac\pi2]$ and $[\frac\pi2,\pi]$.

In the other way you computed the primitive or anti-derivative and then applied the fundamental theorem of infinitesimal calculus. In this case there are no restrictions by monotonicity.

Comment: The substitution rule does not require monotonicity (although some people feel safer with that assumption behind) : $$\int\limits_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(u)\,du =\int\limits_a^bf(g(x))g'(x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Else Use $\int_{0}^a f(x) dx=\int_{0}^a f(a-x) dx$

$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos^3x~ dx=-I \implies 2I =0 \implies I=0$